# How to make other application hidden window visible from my application?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-6

My application hides its window (and hence the task bar button) and stays only in the notification area, with the following code:

```
Form1.Hide;
```

When I click on the notification icon, the window shows itself with the following code:

```
Form1.Show;
Application.Restore;
```

But I want to show the window when the second instance is executed. I can pass any data from first instance to the second using "file mapping". So far I have only managed how to show the window if it is only minimized (the task bar button exists), with this code:

```
if IsIconic(FirstInstanceApplicationHandle) then ShowWindow(FirstInstanceApplicationHandle, SW_RESTORE);
SetForegroundWindow(FirstInstanceApplicationHandle);
```

So how I make visible first instance window from the second instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is to send a message to the first application to get it to restore itself. There's a whole load of code that executes when the application restores itself. That's what you get with the call you make to `Application.Restore`. That's what you need to happen.

Now, it's hard to get that to happen from the outside. So get the second app to send a message to the first, and then let the first app restore itself. Do call `SetForegroundWindow` as well, as you currently do. Your second app can gift that, but the first app cannot otherwise take it.

You'll need to allow the second app to discover a window handle in the first app to send the message to. Your file mapping approach will allow that. Do make sure that you use a window handle not subject to recreation. For example the `Application` handle or one made with `AllocateHWnd`.